# AutoMapper Resolver: cannot convert

Tags: c#, automapper

*Cannot convert from 'Project.Core.AppContainer.UserTypeResolver' to 'AutoMapper.IValueResolver'*

**Mapper Config**

```
public class MapperConfigurationFactory
{
    public static MapperConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IsInternal, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new UserTypeResolver()));
        });
    }
}
```

**Resolver**

```
public class UserTypeResolver : IValueResolver<User, UserViewModel, string>
{
    public string Resolve(User user, UserViewModel userViewModel, string userType, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return user.IsSuperUser ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

I went through several tutorials and I can't find what is wrong. I even tried to change the line with *.ForMember* like this, but it doesn't work either.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.IsInternal, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<UserTypeResolver>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps IsInternal is not a string?